# Removing files from a Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I have a solution that includes a Setup Project. Unfortuately it also includes all the debug symbols, so they are to be removed. Is the correct way to:

1. Right Click in the solution folder on each msi-name (or whatever it is) and select View -> File System
2. In the "File System on Target Machine", select Application Folder.
3. Then select each "Debug Symbols from..."-file from all the folders and delete them.

Is there more to it than this? I guess the dependencies list would automatically shrink and not include any pdb-files eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are building a release build and the release configuration of your application is not generating debug symbols.

The setup project will collect all output from your main project. If the output includes debug symbols, they will show up in the setup as well.

The easiest way to disable debug symbols from being generated is to open your solution in Visual Studio. Find the project that builds your application in the solution explorer. Right-click on the project icon to open it's properties. Make sure you have selected the Release configuration at the top of the dialog. On the *build* tab, select the *Advanced* button at the bottom. This opens a dialog that allows you to control the debug information generated for this configuration. Set the debug info to *none* to make sure no debug information is generated.

Comment: I have "Debug", "Release" and "Configuration Manager...". I have selected the "Release". How do I make sure that my release configuration doesn't generate debug symbols? All the projects have Configuration = Release next to them in the Configuration Manager window.

Comment: @Kasper I have added an explanation of how to set the debug information generated for a project to my answer.

Comment: Ecellent. Thank you very much. The solution consists of 47 smaller projects, so I guess I'll have to traverse them and disable the pdb-files for each of them.

Comment: I have removed them as described but they are still listed as dependencies in the Setup Project.

Comment: Are there .pdb files in the installer that the setup project produces?

Comment: They are no longer being generated by the build process. Thank you for your help.

Comment: But be aware that you should always generate pdbs even for release builds if you ever want to debug a release build to repro a customer issue or if you want to load a memory dump. In general it is a very bad idea to not have pdbs for a release build.